# Macro LocalVar using LocalVar in filename on Export

Tags: macros, ms-access-2010, local-variables

I asked a similar question awhile back which got a response, and I applied their logic but it still doesn't work.

Here is what I'm doing
[image]

I am setting the LocalVar fine, this works.

But I want to add it to the end of the filename, but it comes out literally exactly the way it looks in the Filename.

This is my output:
[image]

Anyone know what's going on? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing some double quotes. You have ...

```
="\\fhnsrv02\CCAIFTP\CCAICMSO\Dropoff\CMSO_PROV_Extract--SPD & [LocalVars]![FileDate] & .xlsx"
```

... which is one long literal string. Try this instead:

```
="\\fhnsrv02\CCAIFTP\CCAICMSO\Dropoff\CMSO_PROV_Extract--SPD" & [LocalVars]![FileDate] & ".xlsx"
```